# input range with two cursor in android studio

Tags: android

I want to have an alertDialog with input type range and two cursors for make selection like this
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y0S5P.png)

Thanks

Comment: Could you show us what you have been trying to do so far?

Comment: i have found the solution here : https://github.com/YahooArchive/android-range-seek-bar. And it work perfectly

Comment: And thank you for your help